# How to connect a JProfiler session with the designed ID?

Tags: jprofiler

I 've started a Java application with the args :

```
"-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849,id=134,nowait"
```

then the console showed:

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 37
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
JProfiler> Using config file C:\Users\user\.jprofiler7\config.xml (id: 134)
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Using dynamic instrumentation
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
JProfiler> Hotspot compiler enabled
```

Then I could connect by JProfiler GUI now.

**But I need connect that via another Java application with JProfiler API**. 
**How could I connect that ? By any VM argument ?**

I just know maybe I have to create a  connection first , but I don't know how to choose the session ID.

```
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createRemoteConnection("localhost", 8849, 30);
```

If I ran the agent application then connect via JProfiler GUi firstly ,I could get the cpu information by my Java application , including then running my JProfiler API application .

```
Profiling data :
Hot spots:
Top 5 hot spots:
Hot spot 1: ProfilerTest.main(java.lang.String[ ]): 34 ms (100 %)
Backtraces: 
ProfilerTest.main(java.lang.String[ ]): 34722 (0)
   ***: 34722 (0)
Cpu tree:
***: 34722 (0)
   ProfilerTest.main(java.lang.String[ ]): 34722 (0)
      java.util.Scanner.next(): 34722 (0)
```

But I'll get nothing if I ran the agent application then connect via my JProfiler API application firstly.

```
Profiling data :
Hot spots:
Top 5 hot spots:
Cpu tree:
***: 0 (0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ",nowait", add ",config=[path to config file],id=nnn" where "[path to config file]" is %USERPROFILE%.jprofiler8\config.xml and "nnn" is the session ID that is visible in the top-right corner of the application settings tab in the session settings dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I could see the session in JProfiler. But I wanna connect a session by my Java application via JProfiler API.How can I connect by designed session ID ? Or it's also better if I could show the designed program's information without session ID ,such as CPU and Memory .

Comment: The session ID is just used for the profiling settings. With the API, you just connect to the profiled application, there is no way to start a session in JProfiler.

Comment: Oh!I have a question? I run the Java application with an argument "-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler7\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849,id=134,nowait" , but I could connect it via JProfiler with a "151" session ID ? then how the JProfiler know which application is right? and do I have a chance to connect a designed application by JProfiler API ?

Comment: At first,I thought that I just need to create a connection with a designed port like 8849, then the analyze program will find the application automaticly. But in fact, if there is no designed session ID , just started with agentpath ,I could get a right result via JProfiler API after connected by JProfiler GUI,  but get a none result if I connected directly by JProfiler API. If I designed a session ID firstly, the JProfiler GUI is also could work , but the JProfiler API just get a none result. I just want to find a way to analyze any java application by my code via JProfiler API directly.

Comment: The session determines the profiling settings. If you connect with a different session from the GUI, some classes might need to be re-instrumented. It's just a matter of efficiency and lower overhead. You can use the platform API only if you add the ",offline" parameter to the -agentpath parameter.